# rails - has_many categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From a person record I need to be able to add/display documents of specific types. Including the conditions for category_id works but at this point I can not assume that the category ids will remain the same as development progresses.  This is also an issue with testing where I only create the categories I need.

Is there a way I can dynamically set the category_id, for example something like this:

```
has_many :personal_documents, :as => :documentable, :conditions => "category_id = #{DocumentCategory.find_by_name('Personal').id}", class_name: 'Document'
```

Models:

```
Person < AR::Base
  has_many :documents, :as => :documentable
  has_many :personal_documents, :as => :documentable, #:conditions => "category_id = 1"
  has_many :legal_documents, :as => :documentable,  #:conditions => "category_id = 2"
end

Animal < AR::Base
  has_many :documents, :as => :documentable
end

Document < AR::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply use seeds with static ids?